# sql in php not returning anything

Tags: php, mysql

How do I see what is returned from a sql statement in php?  I have the following function to get user name from mysql database and I use echo in another php to see the result but nothing shown.

```
function get_user_name($id_user) {
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT username FROM user WHERE id_user = '$id_user'"));
}

echo $id_user;
$a = get_user_name($id_user);
echo $a;
```

Can anyone help?  Thanks.

Comment: You should also insert the data base connection.

Comment: You need to do proper error checking using `mysql_error()`.

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` functions. Use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead.

Comment: Don't just assume `mysql_query` worked!  *Always* check if it did or not.

Comment: @RocketHazmat To add to that, also check that your connection succeeded, and your selecting of the database succeeded.

Comment: [`mysql_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) takes 2 parameters.  You should've seen an error.

Comment: database connection added already.  Also added mysql_error but nothing shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you `echo`ing the `get_user_name();` function?? OR are you even connected to your database? these are two things you need to check before, (if the problem remains) including an error handling method i.e. `or die(mysql_error())` at the end of your query to find out the problem.

```
return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT id_user FROM user WHERE id_user = '$id_user'")or die (mysql_error()));
```

The error handling construct?? in mysql `mysql_error()` should output the problem in fairly understandable way, as to what is preventing your query not to be shown

Comment: I simply used $a to hold the result and use echo to see how it looks like.  These are temporary code to see if sql is working, does it make sense?

Comment: Have you tried to add `or die(mysql_error())` first? if then, what does it show you?

Comment: It shows "No database selected" but it didn't show connection error.

Comment: "No database selected'' means you are not connected to mysql database, and btw that is an error

Comment: Okay, I found it.  The connect-to-db function was altered.